# Set auto-indent not to indent labels

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indentation, auto-indent

I'm using Eclipse CDT on Windows.  I should add that I'm delighted, overall, with the auto-format feature.

But one thing bugs me.

I can't figure out how to configure Eclipse to *not* indent lines with labels.

This is what I want:

```
void myfunc() {
    goto MYLABEL;

MYLABEL:
    return;
}
```

but what I get is this:

```
void myfunc() {
    goto MYLABEL;

    MYLABEL:
    return;
}
```

How can I configure Eclipse to get *exactly* what I want?

In `Code Style --> Formatter`, there's no section for "labels" under "Indentation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in eclipse. I filed it in 2009 and it has yet to be fixed.

The C/C++ development tools plugin seems to be very poorly maintained, as I have quite a few bugs and enhancement requests outstanding which have languished for years.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=268404

Comment: @Luciano Sadly, none I'm aware of (other than manually reformatting, obviously). You can vote on the bug, not that I think it will actually do anything.