# Eclipse code formatting for labels and comments

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to configure `label:` indentation and white space after `//` tags?

For example, I want change this code

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // comment
        int num = 0;
        label: while (num <= 10) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); //comment
        int num = 0;
label:  while (num <= 10) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any options about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't easily reformat labels or comments as you wish using Eclipse:

**Reformatting Labels**

- Eclipse Bug 268404 is still open for this issue ( [Allow formatter rules for labels](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=268404)). It was created in 2009!
- See also SO post [Set auto-indent not to indent labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994909/set-auto-indent-not-to-indent-labels)

**Reformatting comments**

- There is no way to remove whitespace immediately after the opening of a single line comment in Eclipse.
- See the screen shot below for the formatting options available for comments with Eclipse formatting. (**Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit... -> Comments tab** )

Also note that although the Eclipse code formatter has many options it is not entensible; there is no way to add your own formatting rules. Eclipse Bug 310602 ([Make the Java Formatter extensible](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=310602)) was raised for this limitation back in 2010.

One possible alternative is to use an Eclipse plugin for your formatting, such as [Jalopy](https://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/) or [Jindent](http://www.newforms-tech.com/products/jindent/plugins/eclipse). However, they are not free, and you would need to research whether they could be configured to do what you want.

[image: eclipseComments]